# What's the English word for something that given attention too much to

Tags: word-request

What's the word to describe something like this :

> Adam : Tony's car is awesome, everybody is talking about it.

Now say, I'm jealous to his car (presumably).

> I : Nah, his car is just ...?

I know that the options for the word may depend on some situations, but for the specific situation for given example above how should I express it? The world itself would be formal.

Comment: I'd offer _**no big deal**_ (as in, "Nah, his car is no big deal"), except you asked for something formal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One word commonly used in this situation is *overrated*. The verb form, *overrate*, means "to rate, value, or estimate too highly". ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overrate).)

> The critics loved that movie, but I think it's seriously overrated.

On the other hand, *overrated* doesn't necessarily imply a large amount of attention. A movie can be overrated by the critics even if only three critics saw it.

Comment: How colloquial is the word "overrated"?

Comment: @Arminius It is not particularly colloquial. Looking through the "Historical Examples" section at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overrated, I found the word used in an 1879 history book called *History of the English People*, by John Richard Green. Read for yourself [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/23642/23642-h/23642-h.htm#Page_162).

Answer (score 3):

One more variant: **overhyped**

> **overhype** 
>   to advertise or praise something more than it deserves in newspapers, on television, online, etc., in order to make people excited about it and want to buy, try it, invest in it, etc. ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overhype))
>
> Make exaggerated claims about (a product, idea, or event); publicize or promote excessively. ([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overhype))

Answer (score 2):

The word that adds that sense of a lot of attention that is not necessarily implied by "overrated" is "overblown".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best option to be directly applied to your intended phrase, but "ostentatious" may help if that's what you intend to imply.

> His car is just ostentatious.

Comment: No, not really. "Ostentatious" means "showy" - it's a property of the object itself, not the people paying attention to it.